# Error, when call SQL procedure

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have error report: 
Error report -

```
ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P018
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at "INSURADM.PACK_PORTAL_FP_AGRSEL", line 831
ORA-06512: at line 48
12801. 00000 -  "error signaled in parallel query server %s"
*Cause:    A parallel query server reached an exception condition.
*Action:   Check the following error message for the cause, and consult
           your error manual for the appropriate action.
*Comment:  This error can be turned off with event 10397, in which
           case the server's actual error is signaled instead.
```

My procedure:

```
46    begin
47    p_ag_id_out :=1941429;
    -- Call the procedure
48    insuradm.pack_portal_fp_agrsel.get_agrcasco(p_ag_id => p_ag_id_out,
49    v_ao_id => v_ao_id_out,
50    v_co_id => v_co_id_out,
51    v_status => v_status_out,
```

It's snippet, where should be error in  Line 831, but i don't know where in 831 error:

```
831    With

832    AAg As
833      (
834        Select aD.Ag_id    ,        
835               aD.Ag_Parent,
836               aD.Ag_Num   
836        From   InsuraDm.Agreement aD  Inner Join  InsuraDm.AgrProduct Ap
837               on ( aD.Ag_Product = Ap.Ap_id )
838        Where  aD.Ag_id = p_Ag_id   
839          And  Ap_vid   = 5           
840      ),
```

What its mean? How solve it?

Comment: check @line 831 of the procedure INSURADM.PACK_PORTAL_FP_AGRSEL

Comment: @KaushikNayak 831 line it's  WITH, where here error

Comment: Actually it is not clear from these code snippet. However, it is clear from the error  shown "ORA-01722: invalid number"  that  an  SQL statement was executed  that tried to convert a string to a number, but it was unsuccessful.Try running the sql query at 831 separately in sql developer and to check for exact line number in the error message.

Comment: What data types are `ad.ag_id`, `p_ag_id`, `ap_vid`?

Answer (score 2):

Try to cast the columns used in the **where** clause. That worked for me.